Half my money is invested in property

Half my money is invested in property.

Can sentence 1 have two meanings, (a) or (b) below, depending on context?
a) the money is currently invested in property. Here, "invested" acts as an adjective.
b) 1 is the passive voice of:
"I invest half my money in property". This is what I usually do. Here "invested" doesn't act like an adjective, but as a simple past participle.

Both meanings are possible, and only context will disambiguate. it could be that the speaker only started regularly investing half his income in property a few months ago, and that so far "property investments" only account for 1% of his total wealth. That's a less likely scenario in absolute terms, but in context, it might obviously be the only meaning that makes sense. But I don't see how those two different meanings have anything to do with the "part of speech" of invested, which I don't think changes here.

(The "missing subject" of the passive isn't necessarily the speaker. S/he might mean that her/his parents / financial advisor / spouse does the actual investing.)

If someone says "half my money is invested in X" they generally mean "half my savings/wealth are invested in X". If it was done regularly/every month, you'd probably say "I invest half my money in X", even if it's not you personally choosing which shares/coins/wine/art to buy. "To invest" can be used in the passive but you have to consider what's the most likely as well as what's grammatical.

Half my money is invested in property [by me, by my brokers]. It's fine as is and the meaning is clear. There are not two meanings. Only the agent changes: by me,by them, by my parents, by my brokers.

@FumbleFingers, do you mean that "parts of speech" doesn't matter in sentence (1)? If the meaning of (1) is "half of my total wealth is invested in property", what do you think the part of speech of "invested" would be? Wouldn't you call it an "adjective"?

Mr.X: I'd say invested is a verb, and as @Lambie points out, only the agent changes. The focus being on meaning, not "syntactic terminology".
